# active gmap4rails map into fancybox lightbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox, gmaps4rails

I feel that I'm missing something very stupid but I was stucked all day with this and didn't found anything to sorted it out. I want to load a map with an user marked in it when a fancybox lightbox is called, the following code is the best and minimal approach that I have but I'm getting:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google

```
= link_to image_tag('map.png'), map_vendor_path(@coupon.vendor), class: 'js-show-map'

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-show-map').fancybox({
      onComplete: function(){
        Gmaps.loadMaps();
        Gmaps.map.addMarkers([{"lng": "7.859409", "lat": "48.023551"}]);
      }
    });
  });
```

the following view is called when click in link

## map.html.haml

```
// 
 it's here just for test
= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails.css'
= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base"
= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps"

= gmaps4rails(@vendor.to_gmaps4rails)

= yield :scripts
```

## application.js

```
...
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./gmaps4rails
```

## application.css

```
//= require gmaps4rails
```

I checked head source code and I see

```
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Map loads fine when not in the lightbox. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: when you say `Map loads fine when not in the lightbox`, how do you load it on the page? ... inline in a `DIV`? ... also what API version (2/3)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1643990

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the following:

- you click the fancybox
- it retrieves gmaps4rails html and scripts
- external scripts aren't loaded on the fly

So you should:

- include manually the js dependencies in your root view
- disable the external js dependencies inclusion (not mandatory though)